Empty response to Graph query on mails in a folder which actually has mail items visible in mailbox
using Microsoft Graph API for last few months. Recently, faced a issue with graph response while retrieving messages in a folder.
The scenario is I can able to see messages in a folder with some unusual tags [unknown] which I cannot open and the message header details also seems empty and every such messages seems to be a calendar invite/request that doesn't directly belong to my mailbox those messages were found. Those messages might be moved in the event of sharing my calendar through any means (don't know how exactly) as it doesn't seem to by my mailboxes calendar events.


Now coming to Graph while retrieving messages for that folder an empty response(no value) with next link is obtained. There were many subsequent nextLinks available all with empty response and then the deltaLink is obtained

But, if the message is moved/Deleted from the folder the delta Response returns the data for message removal.

I'm bit confused with this.
Those messages are not direct events they seem to be the mails sent/received with the calendar invites/requests if a mailbox user has access to another calendar and the messages related to those calendar events are copied/moved to the user's mailbox who has access to it then why not the access to those messages were permitted.
There might be several reasons for disabling the detailed access to the actual messages both in outlook and message retrieval in Graph but giving the delta responses for those messages seems odd.
It would be better if details of such messages were fully exposed or fully blocked - like using the system folder named calendar for these cases might not affect as it is not visible and will be apt than storing it in some random recoverable item folder.
Does someOne faced the similar kind of issue other than that of the the calendar events / know the exact reason behind the scene.
Thanks ;)
